# Shrink content to fit div

Tags: html, css

I have a div into which a description goes. However the div should not exceed a certain width and height.

The content that goes into the div makes the div exceed the limits.

How can I force the content to resize so that it won't make the div exceed the limits?

At the moment my div looks like this.

```
#Description {
    margin-top: 0px;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 230px;
    background-color: #365478;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 500px;
    display:table;                
}
```

This is the HTML that I am using to call up the description div.

```
<?php echo "<div id = 'Description'>" . $output[Description] . "</div>" ?>
```

If it helps you can see the problem on the website i am working on here. luke.dx.am

Comment: is the content text only?

Comment: On you website when the content is larger than div, it applies vertical scroll. What behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

**[`<table>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)** (and those with `display: table`) automatically expand to allow all of their contents to be included, **regardless** of maximum widths specified. It's also strange to want to output a paragraph into a table *directly*. As such, I recommend changing the content to be something like `display: block` instead.

In addition to this, you probably want to add ellipsis to your text, so that  so that it cuts off and shows three dots if there is more text than can fit in the restricted area. This can be done by applying `white-space: nowrap`, `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`, as is done in the following:

```
#Description {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

It should also be noted that I am unable to test manually on your site, due to it being blocked by my filter for sexual content. I can only begin to wonder what you're hosting there ;)

Comment: Thanks. Got it working now. By the way I can assure you the website contains no explicit content (It's actually my school assignment). :)